# Render html of angularjs instead of default rails html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I want use `angularjs` in rails application and I'm new to angularjs. For this, I add `angularjs` file to project and created the below `scripts` and `html`:

`HomeCtrl.js.coffee`

```
@restauranteur.controller 'HomeCtrl', ['$scope', ($scope) ->
  # Notice how this controller body is empty
]
```

`RestaurantIndexCtrl.js.coffee`:

```
@restauranteur.controller 'RestaurantIndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', ($scope, $location, $http) ->
  $scope.restaurants = []
  $http.get('./restaurants.json').success((data) ->
    $scope.restaurants = data
  )
]
```

`main.js.coffee`:

```
@restauranteur = angular.module('restauranteur', [])

@restauranteur.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.when('/restaurants', {
    templateUrl: '../templates/restaurants/index.html',
    controller: 'RestaurantIndexCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
      templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
])
```

I add below code to `application.js`:

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-mocks
//= require angular-route
//= require main
//= require HomeCtrl
//= require RestaurantIndexCtrl
```

and in `application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="restauranteur">
<head>
  <title>Restauranteur</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I created `templates/home.html` and `templates/restaurants/index.html` directories in `public` folder.

now I want render `templates/home.html` on `localhost:3000` and render `templates/restaurants/index.html` on `localhost:3000/restaurants`. But I'm not successful and `rails` is rendered default page. I check my server log, every `js` and `angularjs` file are renderd, but when I go to `localhost:3000/restaurants` url, rails rendered default page of `restaurants`. (restaurants is a model that generated by `sccafold`.) How can I render angularjs html instead of rails html? Any idea?

`server log`:

```
Started GET "/restaurants" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Processing by RestaurantsController#index as HTML
  Restaurant Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants"
  Rendered restaurants/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 11.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Started GET "/assets/restaurants.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Started GET "/assets/staticpage.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Started GET "/assets/angular.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Started GET "/assets/main.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Started GET "/assets/angular/controllers/HomeCtrl.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Started GET "/assets/angular/controllers/RestaurantIndexCtrl.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 16:48:06 +0430
```

Note: For do this, I use [this tutorial.](http://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2013/12/11/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, if you want use routing, you must add this line in your app initialization:

```
@restauranteur = angular.module('restauranteur', ['ngRoute'])
```

And if you want url such as `localhost:3000/restaurants`, you must use html5-routing.

```
@restauranteur.config(['$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
        ...
        ...
    }
]);
```

Otherwise, just try `localhost:3000/#/restaurants`.